# Make error while ARM cross compiling an SQLite test fixture

Tags: linux, sqlite, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to create a `testfixture` for **SQLite** for ARM from a Linux pc.  However, I am unable to compile as I am prompted with errors.

I get the following error,

```
  Make: *** No rule to make target `armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc', \
         needed by `testfixture'.  Stop.
```

Below is the `make` file I am using.

```
#!/usr/make
#
# Makefile for SQLITE
#
# Source code to the test files.
#
# set up compiler and options


TOP = .
INCLUDES = -I"/home/bkrishnan/Downloads/sqlite-amalgamation/testfixture"

CC = armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc 

CFLAGS = -g $(INCLUDES) -DSQLITE_PRIVATE="" -DSQLITE_TEST=1 -DTCLSH=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DSQLITE_CORE

# library files.
LIB = libtcl8.5.so


#-----File Dependencies----------------------

# Source files.
SRC = \
        $(TOP)/tclsqlite.c \
        $(TOP)/sqlite3.c \
        $(TOP)/shell.c
# Source OBJ files.
SRCOBJ = \
        tclsqlite.o \
        sqlite3.o \
        shell.o
# Test source files.
TESTSRC = \
        $(TOP)/test_async.c \
        $(TOP)/test_autoext.c \
        $(TOP)/test_backup.c \
        $(TOP)/test_btree.c \
        $(TOP)/test_config.c \
        $(TOP)/test_demovfs.c \
        $(TOP)/test_devsym.c \
        $(TOP)/test_func.c \
        $(TOP)/test_hexio.c \
        $(TOP)/test_init.c \
        $(TOP)/test_intarray.c \
        $(TOP)/test_journal.c \
        $(TOP)/test_malloc.c \
        $(TOP)/test_mutex.c \
        $(TOP)/test_onefile.c \
        $(TOP)/test_osinst.c \
        $(TOP)/test_pcache.c \
        $(TOP)/test_schema.c \
        $(TOP)/test_server.c \
        $(TOP)/test_stat.c \
        $(TOP)/test_tclvar.c \
        $(TOP)/test_thread.c \
        $(TOP)/test_vfs.c \
        $(TOP)/test_wsd.c \
        $(TOP)/test1.c \
        $(TOP)/test2.c \
        $(TOP)/test3.c \
        $(TOP)/test4.c \
        $(TOP)/test5.c \
        $(TOP)/test6.c \
        $(TOP)/test7.c \
        $(TOP)/test8.c \
        $(TOP)/test9.c \
        $(TOP)/test_fuzzer.c \
        $(TOP)/test_multiplex.c \
        $(TOP)/test_quota.c \
        $(TOP)/test_rtree.c \
        $(TOP)/test_superlock.c \
        $(TOP)/test_syscall.c \
        $(TOP)/test_wholenumber.c \
        $(TOP)/test_loadext.c \
        $(TOP)/test_spellfix.c \
        $(TOP)/test_vfstrace.c \
        $(TOP)/fts3_term.c \
        $(TOP)/fts3_test.c


# Test OBJ files
TESTOBJ = \
        test_async.o \
        test_autoext.o \
        test_backup.o \
        test_btree.o \
        test_config.o \
        test_demovfs.o \
        test_devsym.o \
        test_func.o \
        test_hexio.o \
        test_init.o \
        test_intarray.o \
        test_journal.o \
        test_malloc.o \
        test_mutex.o \
        test_onefile.o \
        test_osinst.o \
        test_pcache.o \
        test_schema.o \
        test_server.o \
        test_stat.o \
        test_tclvar.o \
        test_thread.o \
        test_vfs.o \
        test_wsd.o \
        test1.o \
        test2.o \
        test3.o \
        test4.o \
        test5.o \
        test6.o \
        test7.o \
        test8.o \
        test9.o \
        test_fuzzer.o \
        test_multiplex.o \
        test_quota.o \
        test_rtree.o \
        test_superlock.o \
        test_syscall.o \
        test_wholenumber.o \
        test_loadext.o \
        test_spellfix.o \
        test_vfstrace.o \
        fts3_term.o \
        fts3_test.o 

# Header files used by all library source files.
HDR = \
        $(TOP)/sqlite3.h \
        $(TOP)/btree.h \
        $(TOP)/hash.h \
        $(TOP)/hwtime.h \
        $(TOP)/mutex.h \
        $(TOP)/os.h \
        $(TOP)/os_common.h \
        $(TOP)/pager.h \
        $(TOP)/pcache.h \
        $(TOP)/sqlite3ext.h \
        $(TOP)/sqliteLimit.h \
        $(TOP)/sqliteInt.h \
        $(TOP)/test_intarray.h \
        $(TOP)/test_multiplex.h \
        $(TOP)/test_quota.h \
        $(TOP)/wal.h \
        $(TOP)/vdbe.h \
        $(TOP)/tcl.h \
        $(TOP)/tclDecls.h \
        $(TOP)/tclPlatDecls.h \
        $(TOP)/tclTomMathDecls.h \
        $(TOP)/tclTomMath.h \
        $(TOP)/fts3Int.h        


testfixture$(TEXE): $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRCOBJ) $(TESTOBJ) $(HDR) -lm $(LIB) 

#depend:
#   makedepend -Y $(HDR)

clean:
    rm -f $(TESTOBJ) $(SRCOBJ)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
testfixture$(TEXE): $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRCOBJ) $(TESTOBJ) $(HDR) -lm $(LIB)
```

to

```
testfixture$(TEXE): $(TESTOBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SRCOBJ) $(TESTOBJ) $(HDR) -lm $(LIB)
```

because $(CC) is the command to run, not the target dependencies.

Comment: +1: You might also like to add some `.PHONY` stuff to your answer.